# JBoss 5.1GA, Spring 3, invoking methods in different .wars in a peer-to-peer manner, with security context

Tags: spring, tomcat, jboss, cas

We are looking at re-structuring certificate-authenticated process in a servlet environment from two peer .war files sharing a shared ticketing authentication system to an ee environment not using the ticketing system.

Specifically, the current stack is Tomcat-based with CAS and Spring 3, and we looking to migrate to a JBoss 5.1 environment with Spring but without CAS.  However, a "service" method in .war1 needs to access a "service" method in .war2 - with.war1's acquired certificate authentication authorization available to .war2's method.

Current thinking:  We would prefer to keep the peer-to-peer hierarchy of the two .war files, primarily to reduce the re-factoring task.  But we are not sure we can actually do this thanks to class-loading and security, even though now the two .war files are in in the same .ear context.  Our template to date has been http://blog.springsource.org/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/ but that approach is hierarchical in that the shared method between the two .war files are in the parent, not in a peer .war file.

So far we've mulled putting some sort of facade in the shared parent and injecting the implementations of .war2's method, possibly some sort of messaging, etc.  The idea is to make this work under new environment with as little re-factoring as possible.

Thoughts?

Thanks!